# JPEG NSData of photo turned UIImage turned JPEG is completely different size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation, jpeg

Why are the bytes of the first JPEG image 1/4 the size of the second?

```
[_stillOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:
 ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError * error)
 {
     NSData* imageBytes = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     NSLog(@"Size = %ld", imageBytes.length);

     UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageBytes];
     NSData* imageBytes2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 1.0);
     NSLog(@"Size = %ld", imageBytes2.length);
...
```

First size is 1,528,278 and second size is 4,289,184.
Should they not being roughly the same size?

Is there any way to specify the scaling and compression of the `jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer` ?

Comment: My guess is that with `NSData* imageBytes2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.25);` you should get the same result.

Comment: Nope. 0.85 gives the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Apple's jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation defaults to around 0.85 compression. So by setting UIImageJPEGRepresentation to that I get the same size.